# softKeyBoard push up my layout

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

`softKeyBoard` push up my layout. I tried all the suggestions of the keyboard, but it did not help, the layout is pushed up, I try also add in code this line:        `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`
but this not work. please I need help.

this is my fragment xml.

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/chat_bg"
android:isScrollContainer="false">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chatRetryArea"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <com.android.shanti.customViews.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/groupChatIsNotAvailable"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_dark" />

    <com.android.shanti.customViews.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/chatRetryLoad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="@string/groupChatIsNotAvailableRetry"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_home" />

</LinearLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/chatLoadingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chatHistoryList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/chatTools"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="20dp"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/chatTools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <com.android.shanti.customViews.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/chatMessageText"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:paddingEnd="13dp"
        android:paddingStart="13dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chatSendClick"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:background="@drawable/send_right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chatMessageBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_message_text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chatAttachmentBtn"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_add_attachment"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="false" />

</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
android:name=".main.MainActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

<activity
android:name=".login.signin.SignUpActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Comment: Try only android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

Comment: I tried. it still not work

Comment: @h.g. you want to push the layout when keyboard appears or keep the layout as it is,question is bit unclear  ?

Comment: when keyboard appears the layout is push up - I do not want that it will be happen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the soft keyboard from pushing your view up
Do like this in your relevant activity tag

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

Comment: look! it aleary exists

Comment: have you tried to use only adjustPan with out adjustNothing